# Changing single item in foreach loop

Tags: php, list, foreach, navigation

I would like to generate a navigation menu using `PHP` and its `foreach` loop. So since the "Home" item is a bit different than the others, I would like to call him, and change its style in some certain condition. This code below works fine for all other menu items except the homepage, as it adds `array` to the `<li>` tag for some reason. Can you please show the mistake I make here?

```
<?php
  $menu = array("Home" => "http://mywebsite.com", "Projects" => "/projects/", "About" => "/about/", "Contact" => "/contact/");
  foreach ($menu as $opis => $link)
  {
    if (strtolower($opis) == $_GET['go'])
    {
      $style = "class=\"active\"";
    }
    else
    {
      if (!$_GET['go'] || $_GET['go'] == "home")
      {
        $style[0] = "class=\"active\"";
        echo $style[0] . " ";
      }      
    }
    echo "<li ".$style."><a href=".$link.">".$opis."</a></li>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `$style` to `''`. If you do not, you will keep `class="active"` on next iteration once set.

```
$menu = array("Home" => "http://mywebsite.com", "Projects" => "/projects/", 
"About" => "/about/", "Contact" => "/contact/");
if(empty($_GET['go'])) $_GET['go'] = 'home';
foreach ($menu as $opis => $link)
{
    $style = (strtolower($opis) == $_GET['go']) ? "class=\"active\"" : '';
    echo "<li $style><a href='$link'>$opis</a></li>\n";
}
```

Comment: again, this adds active class to all items

Comment: No, it is reset on each iteration.

Comment: I have checked and it does what I wrote above

Comment: Only if $_GET['go'] is empty. I've optimized it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've added a key to the variable $style when `$GET['go']` is `home` -

```
$style[0] = "class=\"active\"";
```

Change this to `$style = "class=\"active\"";`

Comment: No, this will add extra style for all items, and I want to have styled just one at a time.